# There is something wrong with this JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have developed a script for checking that user has selected a valid month and year for credit card.

```
function validatemonth()
{
var dt = new Date();
var mth = dt.getMonth();
var yr = dt.getYear(); //this seems to return different data in different browsers
yr = yr + 1900;

if(eval(document.PurchaseCredit.cc_expire_month.value) < mth && eval(document.PurchaseCredit.cc_expire_year.value) == yr)
{
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Expiry Date cannot be less than current date."; 
    document.forms['PurchaseCredit'].submit.disabled = true;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = ""; 
    document.forms['PurchaseCredit'].submit.disabled = false;
}
}
```

This script works well in FireFox but does not work in IE7. Why?

Comment: Hint: IE8 has excelent developer tools for debugging javascript and other problems. Also you can test your page in IE7/Quirks mode too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not working because getYear() return different results for different browsers.

> Internet Explorer:
>
> ```
> * Returns four digits for years before 1900 and after 1999.
> ```
>
> Firefox:
>
> ```
> * Returns a value less than 0 for years before 1900. For example, the
> ```
>
> year 1800 returns -100.
>       * Returns a value 100 or greater for years greater than or equal to
>   2000. For example, the year 2008 returns 108.

Your addition of 1900 is relevant only for Firefox.

Easy Solution : Try using getFullYear()

Answer (score 6):

Date.getYear() is browser dependent. In Firefox it returns the number of years after 1900, in IE it returns the full 4 digit year.

Date.getFullYear() returns the 4 digit year in all browsers, so you should always use it instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var yr = dt.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()` - it should work in both. Also, if you use `getFullYear()`, remove the `yr = yr + 1900` line as well.

Answer (score 4):

[`getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is deprecated. Use [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.